# Docker + php + nginx выдает 500 ошибку

Tags: php, nginx, docker

при загрузке файла сервер выдает 500 ошибку.
Используется docker + nginx + php. Окружение развернуто на docker desktop windows.
Не могу найти логи докера, чтобы понять что вызывает ошибку, nginx или php. Я думаю что nginx.
Конфиги
nginx

```
server {
listen 8888;
index index.php index.html;
root /var/www/public;

index index.html;

fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
fastcgi_buffers 32 128k;
client_max_body_size 512M;

#error_log /var/log

location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
}

location /docs {
    try_files $uri $uri/;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
}
```

}

php-ini

```
memory_limit = 512M

upload_max_filesize = 128M
post_max_size = 128M
max_execution_time = 300;
max_input_time = 300;

error_reporting = E_ALL
catch_workers_output = yes
```

docker-compose

```
version: '3.7'

networks:
  backend-network:
    driver: bridge
  frontend-network:
    driver: bridge

services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/nginx/Dockerfile
#    depends_on:
#      - php-fpm
#    links:
#      - php-fpm
    volumes:
    - ./:/var/www
    ports:
    - "8888:8888"
    restart: always
    networks:
      - frontend-network

  php-fpm:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/php-fpm/Dockerfile
    volumes:
    - ./:/var/www
    - ./docker/php-fpm/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini
#    links:
#      - mysql
#    depends_on:
#      - mysql
    environment:
      - "DB_PORT=3306"
      - "DB_HOST=mysql"
    restart: always
    networks:
      - frontend-network
      - backend-network
```

Comment: `docker logs nginx` и в консоль посыпятся логи nginxa

Comment: Пишет просто роут, браузер, ip это я так понимаю access.log а где найти error.log ? Скрин - http://prntscr.com/rbxyeh

Comment: а лог php-fpm ?

Comment: @Naumov скрин -  http://prntscr.com/rbxzcd

Comment: А если в index.php `die('123');` прописать в начале скрипта, отработает?

Comment: @Naumov даже если не вначале а просто перед загрузкой файла то все обработает - https://prntscr.com/rby2e7

Comment: У вас где то синтаксическая ошибка скорее всего, в логах php смотрите, контейнера.

Comment: Ошибки нет 100%, подозреваю проблема в настройке nginx, я этот же код запустил на Openserver и все заработало. Просто я не пойму как просмотреть error.log контейнера в docker

Comment: Очевидно  же что не в nginx. У вас падает php-fpm и из за того что в compose прописан restart - он поднимается.  Проверьте на предмет точно ли php.ini  у вас подхватывается, ощущение что все дело в параметре максимального размера файла. Ну и само собой посмотрите логи php. error_log  если не знаете где искать, посмотрите вот так `ini_get('error_log');` ну, а вообще говоря  в php.ini это прописывается. Только не забывайте что при рестарте контейнера вы логов не увидите по понятным причинам, примонтируйте к папке логов какую то то папку на хосте чтоб сохранились логи.

Comment: @zalex првоерил, php.ini подхватывается, я установил memory_limit = 1M и поймал ошибку Fatal error: Allowed memory size. Конфиг php.ini изменил на следующий - http://prntscr.com/rbzh8f (скрин) Но ошибки все равно не пишутся в указанный каталог и файл, подскажите как настроить логирование ошибок? ini_get('error_log'); выводит пустую строку, если запустить через openserver то нормальный путь к логам показывает

Comment: По  поводу ini_get() беру свои слова обратно все показывает, путь как и в php.ini "/var/logs/php/error.log" но файла по пусти там нет. Я вызвал ошибку и проверил. Проверяю в том же контейнере где запущен php

Answer (score 0):

Если контейнер создан из официального образа, то там в конфиге докерфайла все логи редиректятса в StdOut. Т.е. docker logs показывает как access.log так и error.log

Comment: nginx docker - http://prntscr.com/rby80o это официальный?

Comment: https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/5c15613519a26c6adc244c24f814a95c786cfbc3/mainline/buster/Dockerfile  вот ссылка на докерфайл из которого у вас генерируется контейнер, там внизу инструкция на редирект файлов access.log/error.log на StdOut т.е. в консоль.

Comment: то есть тут имеется ввиду что я могу зайти в контенер и открыть /var/log/nginx/error.log ?

Comment: Нет, все редиректится в /dev/stdout и /dev/stderr - т.е. файлы access.log/error.log - не файлы, а символьные ссылки. Все логи валятся в docker logs (можно запустить docker logs -f , чтобы следить за логом в реальном времени)

Comment: Отображается только access.log

Comment: Так обновил 5 раз и с 5-го раза загрузился файл, как это понимать ? :)

Comment: Может это такая особенность программа для windows ? К сожалению не могу протестить на данный момент на linux

Comment: @Pavel может стоит увеличить max_execution_time и память

Comment: @Naumov то есть вы думаете, что проблема в настройках php ?

Comment: @Alex ln нам делает ссылку "откуда" - "куда" , а не наоборот, разве нет ?

Comment: ln -s /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/access.log - даже если access.log не существует он создается и начинает ссылаться на /dev/stderr